# Selenium is not calling the website

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying selenium for the first time. My code is as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as EC
import os
import time


class expediaUnitTest():

def __init__(self):
 options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
 options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
 options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
 dir_path=os.getcwd()
 chromedriver=dir_path+"\chromedriver"
 os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"]=chromedriver
 driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options,executable_path=chromedriver)

def timerPractice(self):
    time.sleep(5)

def gotoexpedia(self):
    self.driver.get("https://www.expedia.com/")

def teardown(self):
    self.driver.close()



if __name__=="__main__":
  obj=expediaUnitTest()
  obj.gotoexpedia()
```

A new chromebrowser is called but it does not access the webpage. I get the errormessage:

```
   AttributeError: 'expediaUnitTest' object has no attribute 'driver'
```

When i give the timePractise(), it works perfectly,as in the browser disappears after the given number of seconds. But it does not seem to be calling a function.

Ps: I'm following the online tutorial given here:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zZjucAn_JYk
He doesn't have the problem that I'm having.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `self` when creating the instance of the driver. So instead of

```
driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options,executable_path=chromedriver)
```

it should be

```
self.driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options,executable_path=chromedriver)
```

(in the video they are doing it exactly that way)

Comment: Thank you so much!!